# Show splash screen in blackberry cascade using coding

Tags: blackberry-10

Can you please tell me how to make splash screen using coding. Because i want to fetch data from web service. i have to show splash screen till all data will fetch .so i also show loader above the splash screen ,So please tell me how to do that?

Thank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a pc with me so can't give you code, but the general idea is :

1 show your splash screen

2 connect your slash screen to a signal in your Web request code

3 do your Web request. This will be an asynchronous operation

4 when the Web service request is complete, emit the signal

5 disconnect your splash screen from the signal

6 that's it